# matplotlib not displaying the graph bars

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to get the plot to show on a graph but it does not show anything for some reason. I have properly imported the matplotlib library, I am properly getting the values from the function and when I pass those values to the function where I want the plot to be shown it displays blank image. To show that I am getting the correct values I have used print along with plotting commands the values are getting printed but not the plot Here's the code. I was able to get the plot correct using

```
def GetCounts(data):
    return (data['Sex'].value_counts())

def Get_Plot(Points):
    _x1 = Points[0]
    _x2 = Points[1]
    _y = (_x1 + _x2) - 200
    print('male' + ' ' + str(_x1) + '\n','female' + ' '+ str(_x2), _y)
    plt.bar(height = _x1, tick_label = 'Male', left = _x1)
    plt.xlabel('Counts of people according to Sex')
    plt.ylabel('Number of people')
    plt.show()
Counts   = GetCounts(titanic)
Get_Plot(Counts)
```

I'm trying to get 2 bars placed in there 'Male' and 'Female' and I not sure how I will be able to. and with the code above I am only able to put only one of it.
Please help thanks in advance.

Comment: You should post you code in text form, such that it can be copied from the question. Second, the problem description is not sufficient, what does " but I want to do using function." mean?

Comment: By that, I meant the Get_plot() function would be used multiple time because previously I had to type .plt() on every single line if wanted it plot because I want to plot multiple graphs which will be done with a single function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to revisit the [`plt.bar`](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html) documentation where it says

> `pyplot.bar(left, height, width=0.8, bottom=None, hold=None, data=None, **kwargs)`
>   [...]
>   `left` : sequence of scalars
>   the x coordinates of the left sides of the bars
>   `height` : scalar or sequence of scalars
>   the height(s) of the bars

You may thus position the bars at the indizes `0` and `1` and their height will be given by `Points`

```
plt.bar(range(len(Points)),Points)
plt.xticks(range(len(Points)), Points.index)
```

Comment: when I put plt.bar(range(len([_x1 , _x2])),left =_x1) it gives me an error saying     "range() does not take keyword arguments"

Comment: You cannot give twice the `left` argument to `bar`. Did you acutally try the suggestion from above?

Comment: I was trying to come up with my own idea which does not work at all. Yes, I tried the suggestion you gave me and it works. Thank you! but can you please be more elaborate on which argument does 'range(len(Points)),Points)' take in e.g. left=range(len(Points)) and the rest. I am trying to wrap my head around the code you provided and I am unable to understand so if you can put a little more of your time and explain it will be very helpful for me in future. Thanks again

Comment: In `plt.bar(left, height)` the first argument is `left` and the second argument is `height`.